# Chainlink node connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, chainlink

I'm running a local Kubernets cluster, in this cluster there is an ArgoCD with a PostgreSQL app and chainlink app.
All is deployed without errors but I'm not able to connect to the Chainlink node UI (http://localhost:6688)

The repo to reproduce it: https://github.com/Edu-BS/chainlink-node

When I forward the port I get this exception:

```bash
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6688 -> 6688
Forwarding from [::1]:6688 -> 6688
Handling connection for 6688
E1221 14:25:12.674894   30948 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 6688 -> 6688: error forwarding port 6688 to pod 9bde87d646ad9fd105e117fe0b74f4dff71aa04111cebaa16a3f1261ff14198d, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-bdb94098-7250-c6c7-d6f3-18a9399c05e9": failed to connect to localhost:6688 inside namespace "9bde87d646ad9fd105e117fe0b74f4dff71aa04111cebaa16a3f1261ff14198d", IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:6688: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6 [::1]:6688: connect: connection refused 
E1221 14:25:12.680796   30948 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
Handling connection for 6688
```

And when I get into the pod I get this exception when I run chainlink commands:

```
chainlink@chainlink-8ff64f5c9-gqx6d:~$ chainlink chains evm list
Get "http://localhost:6688/v2/chains/evm": dial tcp [::1]:6688: connect: connection refused
```

The chainlink node is running:

```bash
chainlink@chainlink-8ff64f5c9-gqx6d:~$ ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
chainli+       1  0.5  0.5 2010636 42444 ?       Ssl  12:54   0:10 chainlink local n -p /home/chainlink/.password
chainli+      14  0.0  0.0   4248  3004 pts/0    Ss   12:54   0:00 /bin/bash
chainli+      64  0.0  0.0   4248  2848 pts/1    Ss+  12:58   0:00 /bin/bash
chainli+     380  0.0  0.0   5900  2772 pts/0    R+   13:27   0:00 ps aux
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at your error message:
`failed to connect to localhost:6688 inside namespace "9bde87d646ad9fd105e117fe0b74f4dff71aa04111cebaa16a3f1261ff14198d"`

It appears as though it's looking for port 6688 inside a namespace in your cluster...  but arent you actually trying to connect your host machines localhost with your pod's port 6688?

Just a thought!

Comment: The issue is from the chainlink service, it works when the chainid is wrong.